# Multiply the first value in each column by the next one in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 3D velocity data which i import into matlab from different time steps
the data is then stored into a single array, so for e.g.

```
A = 
1.9003018979277591      3.9313938050246353      1.9550611401555038      4.4729389195345890     -0.1923084604908526
1.9079954278788835      3.9313938050246353      1.9236081195213699      4.4656360727573148     -0.2883623514359477
1.9156889578300083      3.9313938050246353      1.8600046726104833      4.4633941493518368     -0.3745597398775253
1.9233824877811327      3.9313938050246353      1.7774536511804597      4.4684591066449331     -0.4468743057900739
1.9310760177322572      3.9313938050246353      1.6785880816271836      4.4792352570817320     -0.5015682599033333
1.9387695476833817      3.9313938050246353      1.5789717220681783      4.5015318412785614     -0.5414950892833046
1.9464630776345062      3.9313938050246353      1.4803758914752310      4.5382688538970140     -0.5671639103123366
1.9541566075856309      3.9313938050246353      1.3954540252731027      4.5972897305115961     -0.5822441272159316
1.9618501375367554      3.9313938050246353      1.3209857949421817      4.6788923156623099     -0.5844651059587465
```

The data above is a single array which will contain all the V velocity values for a range of time steps. i want to now multiply the first value of each column by the following, so e.g 1.9003*1.907, then 1.9003*1.915, so the same for the next column and for any number of columns. i want to store the values of these into another single array. i need some help on how to do the multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`bsxfun`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) with `times` like this:

```
req = bsxfun(@times, A(1,:),A(2:end,:));
```

If you have MATLAB R2016b or later, you can use implicit expansion like this:

```
req = A(1,:) .* A(2:end,:);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do, although I am sure there is a more elegant way

```
B = repmat(A(1,:), size(A, 2), 1); C = A;
C(2:end,:) = A(2:end,:).*B(2:end,:);
```

`A` is your initial matrix and `C` is your final answer.